# Javascript file not picking up reference to a Angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My `EventController.js` isn't recognising the reference to my `ng-app="eventsApp"`(from app.js).

Following https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angularjs-fundamentals. It works for him but i keep on seeing `{{event.name}}` instead of "Angular Boot Camp" in `EventDetails.html`. Upon running `.js` file it says

```
    eventsApp.controller('EventController',
^

ReferenceError: eventsApp is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Angular Training\DemoApp\app\js\controllers\EventController.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EventDetails.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="eventsApp">

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{event.name}}
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EventController.js:

```
    'use strict';

eventsApp.controller('EventController',
function EventController($scope){

    $scope.event = {

        name:'Angular Boot Camp',
        date:'21/05/2017',
        time:'21:24'
    }
}

);
```

Please advice what am i doing wrong.

Comment: How did you declare the "eventsApp"?

Comment: `var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);` in `app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path for scripts was referenced incorrectly

Expected :

```
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
```

Actual:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
```

Hence why, EventController wasn't recognising the reference

Answer (score 0):

If the **EventController** is in a different file you should write:

```
    angular.module('eventsApp').controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope) {

        $scope.event = {

            name: 'Angular Boot Camp',
            date: '21/05/2017',
            time: '21:24'
        }
    }

);
```

see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lF6mbkMVyXSWMWFj5dIq?p=preview

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank for the tip however, it now picks up on `angular` saying `ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

Comment: I've added a plunker check to see if you have any differences

Comment: Only difference i can see is in Plunker, CDN link is used but i have `angular.min.js` file locally which shouldn't create a problem, but the error still persists

Comment: Make sure that the path for your angular.js is currect, and you can try and replace to the CDN one just to see if it works to eliminate other problems